# A resource failed to call dispose - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm testing mobile ads in Flutter, everything works fine for now. But sometimes I see this error in debug console.

```
W/System  (21924): A resource failed to call dispose.
```

This error does not cause problems in the operation of the application and the ads are working. But I want to know if it can return to an important error when I switch to the release mode in the application.

**Interstitial ad:**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'ad_helper.dart';

class AdController extends GetxController {
  InterstitialAd? interstitialAd;
  int adCounter = 0;
  int interstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
  int maxAttempts = 3;

  void showAd() {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
      interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
        onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          ad.dispose;
          createAd();
        },
        onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
          ad.dispose;
          createAd();
          print('failed to show the ad $ad');
        },
      );
      if (adCounter % 15 == 0) {
        interstitialAd!.show();
        interstitialAd = null;
      }

      adCounter++;
      print("adCounter:" + adCounter.toString());
    }
  }

  void createAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: AdHelper.interstitialAdUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          interstitialAd = ad;
          interstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
          print('$ad loaded');
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          interstitialLoadAttempts += 1;
          interstitialAd = null;
          print('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error.');
          if (interstitialLoadAttempts < maxAttempts) {
            createAd();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    createAd();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    interstitialAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Ad usage:**

```
import 'package:ads_test_deneme/ads/ad_controller.dart';
import 'package:ads_test_deneme/page1_content.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AdController adController = Get.put(AdController());

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Center(
            child: Text("Page1"),
          ),
          Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              adController.showAd();

              Get.to(const Page1Content());
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: const Text(
                "Content",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It means you are trying to dispose a resource that is already destroyed, can't help much without code

Answer (score 0):

> Dispose is a method triggered whenever the created object from the
> stateful widget is removed permanently from the widget tree. It is
> generally overridden and called only when the state object is
> destroyed. Dispose releases the memory allocated to the existing
> variables of the state.

In Your Case , the state already removed so its not calling

Comment: I added the codes, could it be something related to getx?

Answer (score 0):

In this case , you are simply calling a state which is already removed from the context. PLease provide code for further explanation.

Comment: Codes have been added. Could getx be causing this?

Comment: yes if you are using Getx, thats a great chance coz Getx does those thing under the hood. Somehow dispose is called twice.